# ABAP OPEN SQL in re-engeneering an old program

Tags: abap, sap-erp, opensql

I am re-engeneering an old program to an S4/HANA system and I have stack in the below code:

```
 LOOP AT ITAB.
  CLEAR lv_stufe.
  SELECT SINGLE stufe FROM prps INTO lv_stufe
   WHERE pspnr =  itab-projk .
  IF lv_stufe <> '1'.
      CLEAR : lv_up.
      SELECT SINGLE up  FROM prhi INTO lv_up
                          WHERE posnr = itab-projk .
      CLEAR : lv_up1.
      SELECT SINGLE up  FROM prhi INTO lv_up1
                          WHERE posnr = lv_up.
      CLEAR itab-prart.
      SELECT SINGLE prart FROM prps INTO itab-prart
                         WHERE pspnr =  lv_up1.
  ENDIF.
ENDLOOP
```

Can we do it in 1 select?
Thanks
Elias

PS. Thanks Sandra. I think the below solves the problem. Of couse I already have change the ITAB to a more proper and I will create a GT table. Is it OK the below? My only concern is if I need LEFT or INNER. I think I need INNER.

```
select from prps inner join prhi
    on prps~posnr = prhi~posnr
  left join prhi as prhi2
    on prhi~up = prhi2~posnr
fields prps~prart
where prps~stufe <> 1 and
      prps~posnr = @itab-projk
into @itab-prart.
```

Comment: It's easy to refactor existing SQL statements to be joined, by using `EXISTS`. The main issue is about `LOOP AT ITAB`, you should use CDS View, GTT or whatever. Please analyze again, so that to ask a more precise question.

Comment: Thanks Sandra, as almost always your ideas gave me the solution as you can see in PS.

Comment: NB: For code review, you could post on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Sorry but your edit doesn't reflect my comments, but you could at least think of a solution so I'm happy to know.

Comment: @SandraRossi, the question needs work before it's suited to [codereview.se]. You could have pointed the asker at [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. we need a good description of the *purpose* of the code to give context, and question titles should simply say what the code *is for* (the question is always, "_How can I improve this?_").  It's important that the code works correctly; include the unit tests if possible.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's better suited for code review